# Incorrect State for operation: "new", allowed States: "[running,starting]"

Tags: mongodb, jestjs

There is just one test case that I'm testing. I verified the MongoDB methods and they seem to be up to
date. No open issues on GitHub as well.

```
Error:    at MongoMemoryServer.getUri (node_modules/mongodb-memory-server- 
          core/src/MongoMemoryServer.ts:706:15)
          at src/test/setup.ts:7:32
          at src/test/setup.ts:8:71
          at Object.<anonymous>.__awaiter (src/test/setup.ts:4:12)
          at Object.<anonymous> (src/test/setup.ts:5:22)   



import { MongoMemoryServer } from "mongodb-memory-server";
import mongoose from "mongoose";

let mongo: any;
beforeAll(async () => {
  mongo = new MongoMemoryServer();
  const mongoUri = await mongo.getUri();
  await mongoose.connect(mongoUri);
});

beforeEach(async () => {
  const collections = await mongoose.connection.db.collections();
  for (let collection of collections) {
    await collection.deleteMany({});
  }
});

afterAll(async () => {
  await mongo.stop();
  await mongoose.connection.close();
});
```

Answer (score 4):

channge the line `mongo = new MongoMemoryServer();` to `mongo = await MongoMemoryServer.create()`

Comment: I figured this line was missing - "await mongo.start()"

Answer (score 2):

I had your same issue and by looking at the [documentation](https://nodkz.github.io/mongodb-memory-server/docs/api/classes/mongo-memory-server) I figure out that you first have to create the object with `new` and then start the instance with start():

```
mongod = new MongoMemoryServer()
await mongod.start()

const uri = await mongod.getUri()

const mongooseOptions = {
    useNewUrlParser:true,
};

await mongoose.connect(uri,mongooseOptions)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 options to solve this problem:

1- Change the line:

```
mongo = new MongoMemoryServer();
```

to:

```
mongo = await MongoMemoryServer.create();
```

2- Change the lines:

```
 mongo = new MongoMemoryServer();
 const mongoUri = await mongo.getUri();
 await mongoose.connect(mongoUri);
```

To:

```
mongod = new MongoMemoryServer()
await mongod.start()

const uri = await mongod.getUri()

const mongooseOptions = {
useNewUrlParser:true,
};

await mongoose.connect(uri, mongooseOptions)
```